# Yugabyte replication and clustring per Database or Keyspace

Tags: yugabytedb

Is it possible to config replication factor and clustering for each database(or keyspace) or we must just config it for hole yugabyte instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, replication factor is per cluster/universe, and cannot be specified at the database/keyspace level. Could you please file a GitHub issue for this enhancement? It is something that was planned but we did not get around to it.

Not sure what you mean by clustering... all databases/keyspaces and their replicas in a node are allowed to use all nodes in the cluster.  Could you please explain what you're trying to achieve?